# Google Search Results In SiteCore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, google-search-appliance

I have a Google Mini setup to index a SiteCore site. I have XSLT configured to display my search results, as desired.

How do I get this XSLT into a search results page in SiteCore? I have it setup as a rendering, but it seems to break every time. Has anyone done something similar, and have an idea of how to set it up and how the parameters should be?

Comment: Please provide the code that is breaking or the error. Without that, there's nothing to action on to help.

Comment: we have setup google mini before using XSLT and it works fine, there could be something wrong in your XSLT code, can you share that?

Comment: Do you have your XSLT in SiteCore as a rendering, or are you just linking off to the mini itself? The XSLT loads fine on the mini, it's just an issue of getting it into the project and getting sitecore to recognize it.

Comment: Again, please provide details, like code or the error. Saying it doesn't work isn't much to help people help you.

Comment: The XSLT file in question is around 3200 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this isn't possible.

Here's the thread from the CTO of sitecore.

http://sdn.sitecore.net/forum//ShowPost.aspx?PostID=37004

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to understand your situation... To me it looks like you've copied the XSLT from the mini and pasted it into sitecore, is that right? I haven't done that but if you're going to render the results in sitecore you need to get the XML results from the mini. You do that by removing the proxystylesheet parameter and it's accociated value in tje request URL. Have you done that?